# How HTML Form Tag Effect on search result

Tags: forms, html, search-engine, web-crawler

I wonder if form tag wrapping div contents will effect on search engines result (like Google,bing,yahoo)

```
<form onsubmit="return oQuickModify.bInEditMode ">
     <div class="post">
          <div id="msg_4" class="inner">
               Post contents here ....
               ............
               ............
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

^^ this is SMF board post viewing format

Answer (score 0):

It will have no effect whatsoever.